# iPhone - Parse JSON and update labels fast

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json

i'm parsing a json array in my application. If I log the values, it prints the values right away into the console. After the NSLog line, im calling a method, which should update my labels with the new values. After a long time the labels are updated with the new value. 
But it takes very long! So my question is:

Is there a way to perform a faster update of the labels?

Here is a short part of my code:

im calling the JSON parse method here:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self getJSON];
    });
```

Here code from the getJSON method:

```
for(NSDictionary *data in array){

NSLog(@"Value1: ", [data objectForKey:@"Value1"]); // Very Fast

sValue = [data objectForKey:@"Value1"];

}
[self updateLabel];
```

Update label is just

```
lblValue.text = sValue;
```

Comment: When are you doing it - is it asynchronous request ?

Comment: what size of your JSON file, can you give some example of your output?

Comment: Is is standard UITAbleViewCell or a custom cell class ?

Comment: Check my edit. Its not that big. Its one array with 6 values. And im not using a TableView. Just a simple View

Comment: I don't understand two things:  1) Why use an async dispatch to do a simple scan of an array?  2) Why, if you're only going to use the last value fetched, do you scan through all elements of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your code is executed in a **background thread**. Try doing this:

```
for(NSDictionary *data in array){

    NSLog(@"Value1: ", [data objectForKey:@"Value1"]); // Very Fast

    sValue = [data objectForKey:@"Value1"];

}

__weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;

    if (strongSelf)
    {
        [strongSelf updateLabel];
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't know. I just copied/pasted the code from the original question. :)

Comment: I really don't care about the reason and the down-vote :), the answer was just for it's question, not to fix the bug.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense  :)

Comment: For us it doesn't, but I think that he may removed or commented out some code from the loop and it didn't include here and the sValue assignment is just for testing. Don't know :)

Comment: @arturgrigor That makes sense. I'll remove that down-vote. The important bit has been shown: UIKit methods (most of them) must be executed on the main thread. :)  (you need to edit your post in order to make this effective)